# Ajax is not working after lending the page after navigation from main menu. It works only after using submit button once

Tags: jsf, primefaces

What I doing is just an application where the selected option display in the textArea. But Ajax is not working after lending the page after navigation from the main menu on this page. That function only works after using the submit button.

Below is my JSF page code

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                template="/WEB-INF/template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="title">
        Ajax Framework - <span class="subitem">Basic</span>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="description">
        This example demonstrates a simple but common usage of posting the form, updating the backend value and displaying the output with ajax.
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="implementation">

   <h:form>
    <p:panel id="panel" header="Form" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <p:messages>
        <p:autoUpdate />
    </p:messages>

    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">

        <p:outputLabel for="lazy" value="Lazy:" />
        <p:selectOneMenu id="lazy" value="#{selectOneMenuView.option}" lazy="true" style="width:125px">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue="" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{selectOneMenuView.options}" />
            <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{selectOneMenuView.onChange}" execute="@this" render="textarea1"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="PF('dlg').show()" icon="ui-icon-check" />

    <p:dialog header="Values" modal="true" showEffect="bounce" widgetVar="dlg" resizable="false">
        <p:panelGrid columns="2" id="display" columnClasses="label,value"> 
            <h:outputText value="Lazy:" />
            <h:outputText value="#{selectOneMenuView.option}" />
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>               
    <h3>AutoResize</h3>
    <p:inputTextarea id="textarea1"  value="#{selectOneMenuView.inputTextArea}" rows="6" cols="33" />
    </p:panel>
</h:form>            
    </ui:define>


</ui:composition>
```

And my managed bean is as below

```
package org.primefaces.showcase.view.input;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItemGroup;

import org.primefaces.showcase.domain.Theme;
import org.primefaces.showcase.service.ThemeService;

@ManagedBean
public class SelectOneMenuView {

    private String console; 

    private String car;  
    private List<SelectItem> cars;

    private String city;  
    private Map<String,String> cities = new HashMap<String, String>();

    private Theme theme;   
    private List<Theme> themes;

    private String option;  
    private List<String> options;

    private String inputTextArea;


    public String getInputTextArea() {
        return inputTextArea;
    }

    public void setInputTextArea(String inputTextArea) {
        this.inputTextArea = inputTextArea;
    }

    @ManagedProperty("#{themeService}")
    private ThemeService service;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //cars
        SelectItemGroup g1 = new SelectItemGroup("German Cars");
        g1.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[] {new SelectItem("BMW", "BMW"), new SelectItem("Mercedes", "Mercedes"), new SelectItem("Volkswagen", "Volkswagen")});

        SelectItemGroup g2 = new SelectItemGroup("American Cars");
        g2.setSelectItems(new SelectItem[] {new SelectItem("Chrysler", "Chrysler"), new SelectItem("GM", "GM"), new SelectItem("Ford", "Ford")});

        cars = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
        cars.add(g1);
        cars.add(g2);

        //cities
        cities = new HashMap<String, String>();
        cities.put("New York", "New York");
        cities.put("London","London");
        cities.put("Paris","Paris");
        cities.put("Barcelona","Barcelona");
        cities.put("Istanbul","Istanbul");
        cities.put("Berlin","Berlin");

        //themes
        themes = service.getThemes();

        //options
        options = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            options.add("Option " + i);
        }
    }

    public String getConsole() {
        return console;
    }

    public void setConsole(String console) {
        this.console = console;
    }

    public String getCar() {
        return car;
    }

    public void setCar(String car) {
        this.car = car;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public Theme getTheme() {
        return theme;
    }

    public void setTheme(Theme theme) {
        this.theme = theme;
    }

    public List<SelectItem> getCars() {
        return cars;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public List<Theme> getThemes() {
        return themes;
    }

    public void setService(ThemeService service) {
        this.service = service;
    } 

    public String getOption() {
        return option;
    }

    public void setOption(String option) {
        this.option = option;
    }

    public List<String> getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(List<String> options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public void onChange(){ 
        this.inputTextArea = this.option;
    }

}
```

May I know why? Can anyone give me some guideline?

Comment: what is the use of render="textarea1"? Shouldn't it be update="textarea1"

Comment: He is using f:ajax which is render instead of p:ajax which uses update="". I prefer to alway use the p:ajax if I am already using PrimeFaces

Comment: Have you tried setting your ManagedBean to ViewScope?

Comment: Thanks a lot after using p:ajax which uses update="" works